# Correct way to retrieve mails by IMAP in symfony2

Tags: symfony, imap

I have to develop simple mail client in symfony2 using IMAP. Im wondering what is best way to retrieve messages from server (lets take a gmail as example)?

I did something like this:

```
public function indexAction($name)
{
    $user = 'adress@gmail.com';
    $password = 'password';
    $mailbox = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
    $mbx = imap_open($mailbox , $user , $password);
    $ck = imap_check($mbx);
    $mails = imap_fetch_overview($mbx,"1:5");
    return $this->render('HtstMailBundle:Mail:index.html.twig',array('name'=>$name,'mail'=>$mails));
}
```

is this right way, or not? It works, but is it compatible with symfony "standards"?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This has nothing to do with symfony "standards". But you can make your code more OOP if you move all login to a service class and use symfony DepencyInjection to create and get your service:

```
public function indexAction($name)
{
    $user = 'adress@gmail.com';
    $password = 'password';
    $mailbox = "{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
    $mails = $this->get("mail.checker")->receive($user, $password, $mailbox);
    return $this->render('HtstMailBundle:Mail:index.html.twig',array('name'=>$name,'mail'=>$mails));
}
```

Class declaration:

```
class MailChecker
{
    public function receive($user, $password, $mailbox)
    {
        ...imap_check()...
    }
}
```

service declartion:

```
services:
    mail.checker:
        class: Project\YourBundle\Service\MailChecker
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [this Symfony bundle](https://github.com/webeith/imap-bundle) for that and use it as a service. I is designed for old Symfony2 but tested it with Symfony 3 and works :)