# Retrieve and parse emails from (POP3 or IMAP) mailbox in Symfony2

Tags: php, email, symfony

I am looking for a package/bundle that can access an email inbox, retrieve the emails in the inbox and parse them (Sender Email, Subject, Body, Attachments) for processing in my Symfony2 application. The idea is a "helpdesk" where people can email a specific email address and a cron job will run through the email inbox and convert emails into helpdesk tickets (with attachments).

Before anyone tells me to Google or something equally unhelpful, please note that I have spent over an hour on Google as well as gone over more than 100 StackOverflow threads looking for something that can help me with this. Most of the content involves sending emails and not retrieving them. I have built a pure PHP parser before and it was a nightmare (as almost every email client composes the emails a little differently).

I found https://packagist.org/packages/lasso/mail-parser-bundle, but it seems to only be for Zend. I have also found https://github.com/iJanki/MailMimeDecodeBundle, but it seems to still be a work in progress and there is no documentation to speak of. Additionally, I found [Correct way to retrieve mails by IMAP in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182364/correct-way-to-retrieve-mails-by-imap-in-symfony2), but that looks just like the start of the nightmare I had last time when I built one from scratch.

I would appreciate any suggestions or pointers from anyone who has implemented something similar or has been in a similar situation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found a PHP class that does exactly what I wanted and neatly parses the emails into fromAddress, subject, body and attachments. It even saves the attachments to specified location on your server.

https://github.com/barbushin/php-imap

While it is not a Symfony2 Bundle, it is very easy to integrate into Symfony by supplying the class with a namespace and then using it in your desired controller.

Comment: I integrated the php-imap class into my symfony project and it works perfectly.

Comment: I was just trying to this but I have a proble with composer config from symfony clear::cache command which get a problem ! 
Is there a solution with this ?

Comment: Frédéric Klee, the PHP IMAP class is not Symfony specific, but integrates really well. I can advise that the Symfony command to clear the cache is "cache:clear" and not "cache::clear". You can also clear the cache be deleting the folders /app/cache/dev/ and /app/cache/prod/ respectively,but other than that, I do not know what type of issues you are having. Could you be more specific about the problem you are getting?

Comment: There is now a Symfony bundle for this class: https://github.com/secit-pl/imap-bundle

Answer (score 0):

@pusle comment is a better answer for Symfony, and is current (that is, works with Symfony 7, just released 4 months before this answer was written.)

https://github.com/secit-pl/imap-bundle