# How to import mail using symfony2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, email

A few weeks ago I've started using symfony2. First, I wanna say that it works great and I really enjoy all the features and possibilities symfony2 offers.

#### Project

Now that I'm trying to become a symfony2 Guru, I've decided to develop all new projects I start using symfony.

My current project requires me to import email from an imap mailbox, put it into the database and then make a list of emails. Simply said, I'm trying to build a mail client in symfony.

#### The issue

Symfony2 has an infinite range of possibilities and I'm always looking for the best practice. What I would like to know is what the best way would be to import mail.

- Should I be using a cron job to import the mail
- Can I use something like a worker?
- Do I need extra Bundles?

What I'm actually looking for is some advice on how to do this project and where to start.

Comment: if you copy the mails into your database, you will automatically have synchronization issues at some point or you have to invest a huge amount of time into preventing those. I think you should try to work with the imap server directly and use it as your primary data source. And yes, somewhere should exist an imap bundle.

Comment: Also, this question might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182364/correct-way-to-retrieve-mails-by-imap-in-symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I'll post my comment as answer:

If you copy the mails into your database, you will automatically have synchronization issues at some point.
The alternative would be to invest huge amounts of time into preventing those.

I think you should try to work with the imap server directly and use it as your primary data source.
Write yourself a fat service layer containing your business logic that uses something similar to Doctrine Repositories to access the IMAP server. Define your IMAP Repositories as services and inject them into your service layer.

PHP has native support for IMAP, look for the `imap_*` function set. Also, there are a bunch of IMAP bundles, just search for "IMAP" on https://packagist.org.

A very interesting and informative talk from Kris Wallsmith on how to structure your application: http://de.slideshare.net/kriswallsmith/how-kris-writessymfonyappssymfonycon